# How can I consume a stream of json chunks from http endpoint?

Tags: node.js, stream

I have a server that is streaming json objects to an endpoint. Here is a simplified example:

```
app.get('/getJsonObjects', function (req, res) {
    res.write(JSON.stringify(json1));
    res.write(JSON.stringify(json2));
    res.write(JSON.stringify(json3));
    res.write(JSON.stringify(json4));
    res.write(JSON.stringify(json5));
    res.end();
});
```

Then client side using browser-request, I'm trying to do:

```
var r = request(url);
r.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(data));
});
```

The problem is despite streaming to the endpoint chunks of valid stringified JSON, the chunks I'm getting back from the request are just text chunks that don't necessarily align with the start/end of the JSON chunks that were sent from the server. This means that JSON.parse(data) will sometimes fail.

What is the best way to stream these chunks of json in the same way that they were written to the endpoint?

Comment: http://oboejs.com

Comment: For reference here is an example endpoint that I'm trying to string json objects from using request. http://augurnode1.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:8547/getMarketsInfo?branchId=eq,1010101

Answer (score 1):

This is an async problem. The server code you have provided will not be guaranteed to send out data in that order.

You will either have to accumulate the chunks on the client side and determine the order of the chunks on the client end for display or you will have to do some sort of accumulator method on the server end and then output the JSON in order as they get processed.

Edit:
It appears that res.write can take in an encoding type "chunked". So try setting the header field to chunked and then specify "chunked" in the encoding parameter of res.write().
https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback

If this fails, you can just make a huge callback / promise chain using the callback parameter of res.write to guarantee the order of the res.write().

Comment: I will give "chunked" a try. Also, just to clarify I don't actually care that my write order is the same as my read order, only that I can parse the results as valid json when I stream them on the client.

Comment: If that's the case, then you will either have to use the chunked encoding or you will have to determine the order on the client side.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this works. I set `res.setHeader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked');` in my server code before my writes, but I still see the same thing when trying parse the data returned in the stream on the client.

Comment: For the callback/promise issue try [async mapSeries](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.mapSeries)